# convert database table into XML schema file

Tags: sql-server, database, xsd, schema

I am using SQL Server 2005. Is there any command or GUI tool (e.g. any menu/function from SQL Server management studio) to convert database table into XML schema file (.xsd)?

thanks in advance,
George

Comment: Check this link.... To download an Application to convert a SQL Server database table into XML https://sites.google.com/site/createxmlfromdb/

Answer (score 8):

I've found this. Give it a try

```
Select CourseID, Name, CoursePrice
FROM CouseMaster.Course Course
FOR XML AUTO, XMLSCHEMA
```

Comment: @Mork0075, 1. CourseID, Name, CoursePrice are the column names? 2. I think CouseMaster.Course is the table name, but why you add an additional Course after CouseMaster.Course Course?

Comment: This was only a copy and paste snippet. The select and from are not really important, the FOR XML AUTO, XMLSCHEMA should be.

Comment: Cool, I am using "Select CourseID, Name, CoursePriceFROM CouseMaster.Course FOR XML AUTO, XMLSCHEMA" and it works. The last question, the additiona Course after CouseMaster.Course means?

Comment: I dont know, perhaps its a typo and should be FROM x AS y

Comment: @Mork0075, how to output schema to a file?

Comment: This depends on your enviroment. If the run the command on a shell, you should be able to pipe it into a file.

Comment: Currently I run it in SQL Server 2005 Management Studio, how to run it from shell?

Comment: Thank you so much!  Might I suggest you update it to use the following: FOR XML AUTO, ROOT('Root'), XMLSCHEMA  Adding the root will give you well-formed XML that you may use for other applications that may be more discerning.

Comment: I don't understand when I run this in sql I just get errors everywhere what are you running this in?

Comment: you are a lifesaver! I was looking forever to find something like this! thank you. thank you. thank you

Comment: @Alioo post your query maybe I can help

Answer (score 0):

You can write to file like this:

```
bcp.exe "select top 0 * from (select 1 as iCol) as t for xml auto, xmlschema" queryout outfile.xsd -T -c
```

I'm Using the TOP 0 to exclude the xml of the actual query data since you only want the schema. The -c causes it to be plain character data in the output, use -w instead if you want utf-16 (unicode) output.

EDIT - and if you want to change the xml structure, look at PATH with FOR XML.

Answer (score 0):

Declare @SQL nvarchar(1000)
SET @SQL= 'bcp.exe '+ '"select * from  yourdbname.yourschema.yourtablename for xml path (''record''), ROOT (''tabel'')"' +' queryout '+ 'c:\yourfilename.xsd' +'  -w -r -t -SyourServerName -T'

print @SQL
EXEC Master..xp_CmdShell @SQL

Replace allvalues starts with 'your', accordingly